# Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I've looked at quite a lot of topics on this in different forums and none seem to help me.

I recently bought an Elegoo car kit, which is compatible with the Arduino IDE, and it comes with different types of code and what not. they even have their own Android app.

My problem is I want to create my own android Bluetooth application that connects/pairs with the module and can control the car remotely. I have my application up and running, it can scan for nearby devices and the HC-08 module appears in the list but I am not able to connect. when I try to connect it says it can't communicate with HC-08. I am pretty sure the problem lies in the android end as the elegoo Bluetooth app connects no problem at all with the Bluetooth module if there is any code on the elegoo board or not. The bluetooth module is a HC-08.

Can someone help me with this ?

Also I am following this youtube tutorial so the credit goes to him for the code. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ0JQXcNNTA

Here is the main activity code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
Button btnEnableDisable_Discoverable;

public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

ListView lvNewDevices;


// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Broadcast Receiver for changes made to bluetooth states such as:
 * 1) Discoverability mode on/off or expire.
 */
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

            int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (mode) {
                //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                    break;
                //Device not in discoverable mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
};




/**
 * Broadcast Receiver for listing devices that are not yet paired
 * -Executed by btnDiscover() method.
 */
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra (BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mBTDevices.add(device);
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
            mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
            lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Broadcast Receiver that detects bond state changes (Pairing status changes)
 */
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)){
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //3 cases:
            //case1: bonded already
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
            }
            //case2: creating a bone
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
            }
            //case3: breaking a bond
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
            }
        }
    }
};



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called.");
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
    //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
    btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);
    lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
    mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    //Broadcasts when bond state changes (ie:pairing)
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


    btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
            enableDisableBT();
        }
    });

}



public void enableDisableBT(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
        Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);

        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }
    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
    }

}


public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds.");

    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

}

public void btnDiscover(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

        //check BT permissions in manifest
        checkBTPermissions();

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

        //check BT permissions in manifest
        checkBTPermissions();

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
    }
}

/**
 * This method is required for all devices running API23+
 * Android must programmatically check the permissions for bluetooth. Putting the proper permissions
 * in the manifest is not enough.
 *
 * NOTE: This will only execute on versions > LOLLIPOP because it is not needed otherwise.
 */
private void checkBTPermissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if (permissionCheck != 0) {

            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
    String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
    String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

    //create the bond.
    //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
        mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();
    }
    }
    }
```

/// Here is also my DeviceListAdapter code:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;
private int  mViewResourceId;

public DeviceListAdapter(Context context, int tvResourceId, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices){
    super(context, tvResourceId,devices);
    this.mDevices = devices;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = tvResourceId;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(position);

    if (device != null) {
        TextView deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceName);
        TextView deviceAdress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceAddress);

        if (deviceName != null) {
            deviceName.setText(device.getName());
        }
        if (deviceAdress != null) {
            deviceAdress.setText(device.getAddress());
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you... I also had some problems with android-arduino BT connection, but finally I made it working. Do you want me to post my code here? However, I've used HC-06, not HC-08, and Arduino UNO.

Comment: ye that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tutorials on Bluetooth are pretty old! I just got Arduino-Android Bluetooth communication working last week so this should work for you! First in your manifest file add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then use this in your main.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final String DEVICE_ADDRESS="benamekhoda"; //I actually used Device Name instead of address 
private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Serial Port Service UUID
private BluetoothDevice device; //Our Bluetooth Device
private BluetoothSocket socket;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inputStream;
Button startButton, sendButton,clearButton,stopButton;
TextView textView;
EditText editText;
boolean deviceConnected=false;
Thread thread;
byte buffer[];
int bufferPosition;
boolean stopThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(BTinit())
            {
                if(BTconnect())
                {
                    setUiEnabled(true);
                    deviceConnected=true;
                    beginListenForData();
                    textView.append("\nConnection Opened!\n");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BTconnect false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BTinit false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String string = editText.getText().toString();
            string.concat("\n");
            try {
                outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textView.append("\nSent Data:"+string+"\n");
        }
    });
    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickClear(view);
        }
    });
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickSend(view);
        }
    });

    setUiEnabled(false);
}
public void setUiEnabled(boolean bool)
{
    startButton.setEnabled(!bool);
    sendButton.setEnabled(bool);
    stopButton.setEnabled(bool);
    textView.setEnabled(bool);
}

public boolean BTinit()
{
    boolean found=false;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesnt Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); //Something like ArrayList but no duplicate is allowed and data is unordered
    if(bondedDevices.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Pair the Device first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        for (BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices)
        {
            if(iterator.getName().equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS))
            {
                device=iterator;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"found the device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}

public boolean BTconnect()
{
    boolean connected=true;
    try {

        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID);
        socket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"throw1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        connected=false;
    }
    if(connected)
    {
        try {
            outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"throw2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"throw3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    return connected;
}



void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    stopThread = false;
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    Thread thread  = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    int byteCount = inputStream.available();
                    if(byteCount > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                        inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                        final String string=new String(rawBytes,"UTF-8");
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                textView.append(string);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopThread = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"throw4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

public void onClickSend(View view) {
    String string = editText.getText().toString();
    string.concat("\n");
    try {
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView.append("\nSent Data:"+string+"\n");

}

public void onClickStop(View view) throws IOException {
    stopThread = true;
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    socket.close();
    setUiEnabled(false);
    deviceConnected=false;
    textView.append("\nConnection Closed!\n");
}

public void onClickClear(View view) {
    textView.setText("");
}
```

}

I got it from [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/control-an-arduino-using-your-phone/) awesome tutorial by **Hariharan Mathavan** from All About Circuits.

Comment: Thank you. I shall give it a try and post if it works.